# Jquery - Hide some content of 'draggable' div but use it on 'drop' event

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, hide

I have two div on my page. One is **draggable** and other is **droppable**.

Draggable div:

```
<div id='drag'>
    <div id='one'>11111</div>
    <div id='two'>22222</div>
<div>
```

Droppable div

```
<div id='drop'>

</div>
```

I am using following jQuery code to append the contents of div '**drag**' to div '**drop**' on drop event of draggable div.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#drag" ).draggable();
        $( "#drop" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).append( ui.draggable.html();
            }
        });
    });
```

Now what I want to do is , I don't want to show the contents of div '**two**'(which is inside div '**drag**') to the user. But still when a user drops the div '**drag**' on div '**drop**' , the content of both div '**one**' and '**two**' should get appended to div '**drop**'.

So the **user should see the content of div 'drag' as:**(div 'two' is hidden)

```
111111
```

But **after drop of div 'drag', the content of div 'drop' should** be:

```
111111
222222
```

Please guide me how to hide the content of div '**one**' from user, but still use it on drop event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight changes in the markup and js script as follows

```
<div id='drag' style="border:solid 1px blue;height:50px;">
    <div id='one'  >11111</div>
    <div id='two' ><span style="visibility:hidden;">22222</span></div>
</div>


<div id='drop' style="border:solid 1px red;height:50px;">

</div>
```

​

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#drag").draggable();

    $("#drop").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable.text());
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: One more question. How can I append content of only 'div' two to div 'drop'?

Comment: Change code with append API call as ` $(this).append(ui.draggable.find('#two').text());`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dragstop` event exposed by the draggable function in combination with `bind` to achieve the functionality you want.

**Example:**

```
$( "#drag" ).bind( "dragstop", function(event, ui) {
    $( this ).append( ui.draggable.html());
});
```